# Pure regex solution to remove entire text after a certain part of text (in a plist file)

Tags: regex, plist

I've looked through all sorts of questions here, but couldn't find an answer to mine. I want to remove the entire text that follows a particular text part. Not within a string, but really the whole following text!

Here’s an example of a plist (it's really just a simple example. Normally the plist is much longer, but this should have no relevance for the question or answer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>WFWorkflowActions</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>WFWorkflowActionIdentifier</key>
            <string>is.workflow.actions.comment</string>
            <key>WFWorkflowActionParameters</key>
            <dict>
                <key>WFCommentActionText</key>
                <string>Comment</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>WFWorkflowClientRelease</key>
    <string>3.0</string>
    <key>WFWorkflowClientVersion</key>
    <string>1030.14</string>
    <key>WFWorkflowIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>WFWorkflowIconGlyphNumber</key>
        <integer>59771</integer>
        <key>WFWorkflowIconStartColor</key>
        <integer>463140863</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>WFWorkflowImportQuestions</key>
    <array/>
    <key>WFWorkflowInputContentItemClasses</key>
    <array>
        <string>WFAppStoreAppContentItem</string>
        <string>WFArticleContentItem</string>
        <string>WFContactContentItem</string>
        <string>WFDateContentItem</string>
        <string>WFEmailAddressContentItem</string>
        <string>WFGenericFileContentItem</string>
        <string>WFImageContentItem</string>
        <string>WFiTunesProductContentItem</string>
        <string>WFLocationContentItem</string>
        <string>WFDCMapsLinkContentItem</string>
        <string>WFAVAssetContentItem</string>
        <string>WFPDFContentItem</string>
        <string>WFPhoneNumberContentItem</string>
        <string>WFRichTextContentItem</string>
        <string>WFSafariWebPageContentItem</string>
        <string>WFStringContentItem</string>
        <string>WFURLContentItem</string>
    </array>
    <key>WFWorkflowMinimumClientVersion</key>
    <integer>900</integer>
    <key>WFWorkflowMinimumClientVersionString</key>
    <string>900</string>
    <key>WFWorkflowTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>NCWidget</string>
        <string>WatchKit</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to remove everything including and after:

```
</array>
    <key>WFWorkflowClientRelease</key>
```

*All line breaks/new lines must be kept.*

The result would then look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>WFWorkflowActions</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>WFWorkflowActionIdentifier</key>
            <string>is.workflow.actions.comment</string>
            <key>WFWorkflowActionParameters</key>
            <dict>
                <key>WFCommentActionText</key>
                <string>Comment</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

I even found a way to find a solution, but for that I had to remove all new lines, which is not desired. I first used `\n`. Than I replaced `</array><key>WFWorkflowClientRelease</key>` with `lrtxplqw` and then removed everything after and including `lrtxplqw` with `lrtxplqw.*$`. In this very awkward way I managed to have everything removed including and after `lrtxplqw`. But the solution is not satisfactory, because the line breaks/new lines all have to be kept.

I would also be happy to remove the first part, which would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>WFWorkflowActions</key>
    <array>
```

The final result would look like this:

```
<dict>
            <key>WFWorkflowActionIdentifier</key>
            <string>is.workflow.actions.comment</string>
            <key>WFWorkflowActionParameters</key>
            <dict>
                <key>WFCommentActionText</key>
                <string>Comment</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: An NFA regex that matches that whole text to remove is `</array>\s*<key>WFWorkflowClientRelease</key>[\s\S]*`

Comment: Ok, wow Wiktor! Wow! Really! That’s all?! I'm totally impressed! And I must honestly admit that I don't know much about Regex. Whenever I have time, I try to learn. Your solution looks so "simple", but I didn't come close to it. But that’s actually the solution and answer to my question! It works! Thank you soooo much for the quick reply and help! Really awesome! :)

Comment: Even though I know that I would have to create a new question for it, I dare to ask another one anyway: I'd like to remove this first part as well:

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>WFWorkflowActions</key>
    <array>``` 
    
Tbh, I've found a solution withouth Regex, but I'd like to know what the Regex solution would be. Only if you don't bother and it's okay to do this right here. :)

Comment: You  may use a single regex: `^[\s\S]*?<array>|</array>\s*<key>WFWorkflowClientRelease</key>[\s\S]*`

Comment: Wiktor, you’re my personal hero of the day! For you it was certainly a small thing, but for me it really means a lot. Thank you very, very much for all your help. This is the perfect solution! And everything in only one step, brilliant! *How am I supposed to mark this question as answered (since we only speak within the comments section)?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^[\s\S]*?<array>|</array>\s*<key>WFWorkflowClientRelease</key>[\s\S]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hn0gVE/1).

[Regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F%3Carray%3E%7C%3C%2Farray%3E%5Cs*%3Ckey%3EWFWorkflowClientRelease%3C%2Fkey%3E%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*):

[image]

Comment: *haha* Perfect Wiktor, thank you very much. I will add the part to my question above that I want to remove the first part as well. Jeszcze raz bardzo dziękuję i życzę wszystkiego najlepszego. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>buildVersion</key>
    <string>0.9064</string>
    <key>comments</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>data</key>
    <string>&lt;levelXML&gt;&lt;info v="1.70" x="75.00" y="50.00" c="2" f="0" h="0" bg="0" bgc="16777215" e="1" fm="m"/&gt;&lt;/levelXML&gt;        </string>
    <key>force_character</key>
    <false/>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Untitled</string>
    <key>playable_character</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).